# Set membership in Python

Tags: python, set

I have a tuple x such that `x = (1, 2)` and I have a set z. Suppose I do this:

```
z = set(x)
1 in z            # True
2 in z            # True
x in z            # False
```

Why does this happen and how can I add tuples to a set and preserve their properties as tuples?

Comment: the constructor you are using, as you'd know if you'd read the doc, takes an iterable, which a tuple is. Hence, it creates a set that contains all elements of the tuple. To add a tuple to your set, simply use the `add` method

Comment: set constructor takes _iterable_ as argument. Your tuple is a two-element iterable. You need to pass single-element iterable (e.g. `set([x]`), or use a Python 2.7+ syntactic sugar - `z = {x}`

Comment: @njzk2 As a matter of fact, I did read the doc and then asked this question because the doc wasn't clear to me. Maybe next time don't assume ignorance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing any of these instead:

- `z = {x}`
- `z = set([x])`
- `z = set(); z.add(x)`
- `z = set(); z.update([x])`

Answer (score 1):

Pass tuples to your set constructor. If you would pass it like this:

```
x = ((1, 2), )
z = set(x)
1 in z       # False
2 in z       # False
(1, 2) in z  # True
```